# Mostrar link de marcadores en una base de datos

Tags: mysql, google-maps

Tengo una base de datos en mysql con información de inmuebles. ¿Algún indicio de cómo puedo mostarlos en mapa de Google, pero no todos a la vez? Es decir, elijo una dirección inicial, y un tipo de inmueble, y que me muestre los del mismo tipo en un radio "x". Una vez mostrados los marcadores, poder filtrar por tipos, localidades, etc.
Gracias anticipadas

Comment: podrías mostrarnos lo que llevas avanzado y qué te está arrojando hoy?

Comment: hola amenadiel, estoy siguiendo el ejemplo como base de esta página:https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

Comment: Pero cuando busco cualquie rlocalidad, me devuelve un error **Warning: #1292 Equivocado truncado DOUBLE valor: '%s'** al probar la query en phpmyadmin. la idea es algo similar, y que cuando devuelva marcadores en el mapa, luego poderlos filtrar

Answer (score 3):

A ver, efectivamente, cuando se trabaja con geometrías, es normal que las coordenadas se traten como DOUBLE. También le quitaría el uso del motor MyISAM que está harto obsoleto:

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `lng` DOUBLE NOT NULL
) ;
```

Dicho esto, MySQL tiene funciones geométricas hace tiempo (desde la 5.6 creo) y no necesitas andar transformando con el radio de la tierra:

Por ejemplo, tomando ese tutorial de google, podrías obtener los puntos que están a menos de 50Km del punto `{lat:-33.8, lng: 150.5}`

```
SELECT id, name, lat, lng, 
round(ST_Distance_Sphere(Point(lng,lat),Point(150.5,-33.8))) as distancia
FROM markers
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(Point(lng,lat),Point(150.5,-33.8))<50000
```

Eso equivale a hacer un círculo de 50Km en torno al punto mencionado.

[<kbd>DBFiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e1860d8acc3fd603545d9e89a8aaa337)

Para trabajar con geometrías complejas (polígonos de subdivisiones administrativas, por ejemplo) se acostumbra guardar la geometría como binario y no como texto. En general esta disciplina se trabaja más bien con PostgreSQL y su extensión PostGIS que son más eficientes y consistentes que las funciones de MySQL, pero no está de más un ejemplo.

Digamos que ahora la tabla tiene un campo de tipo geometría:

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `lng` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  geom GEOMETRY
) ;
```

Después de llenarla con los datos de google, la actualizamos:

```
UPDATE markers set geom=Point(lng,lat);
```

Ahora podrías consultar directo sobre el campo sin calcular el punto para cada fila:

```
SELECT id,
       name, 
       st_y(geom) as lat,
       st_x(geom) as lng,  
       round(ST_Distance_Sphere(geom,Point(150.5,-33.8))) as distancia

FROM markers
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(geom,Point(150.5,-33.8))<50000
```

[<kbd>DBFiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0165f035d5d4b785b2b0a4e0243d66e4)

En ambos casos el resultado es el mismo:

```
|id |          name        |    lat    |    lng   |dist. |
|---|----------------------|-----------|----------|------|
| 2 | BeeYourself Clothing |-33.729752 |150.83609 | 32035|
| 3 | Dress Code           |-33.949448 |151.008591| 49807|
| 5 | Fashiontasia         |-33.944489 |150.854706| 36476|
| 8 | Buena Ropa!          |-33.815521 |151.026642| 48688|
| 9 | Coxcomb and Lily...  |-33.829525 |150.873764| 34686|
```

Comment: Hago lo que me indicas, pero me da error ST_**Distance_Sphere does not exist** con PHP 7.2.25

Comment: Qué motor de MySQL? Esa función es de MySQL 5.7

Comment: Perdona, la versión es 5.5.64-MariaDB

Comment: MariaDB no tiene esa función, las extensiones geométricas de MySQL ocurrieron después del fork y MaríaDB nunca ha estado muy interesado. Pero hay un petitorio hace más de un año: [MDEV-13467](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467)

Comment: Entonces el ejemplo que he cogido no me sirve entiendo. Lo que necesitaría sería algo del estilo: Tengo una tabla en mysql con listado de inmuebles, son su tipo, dirección, latitud y longitud y provincia. Necesitaría poder mostrarlos en un mapa, partiendo de en vez de mostrar todos de golpe), indicar una dirección y, a partir de ese marcador, poder filtrar por provincia, tipo, radio, etc para que me fuera mostranso el resto y a ser posible, con una tabla de datos bajo el mapa. Gracias ante todo.

Comment: puedes mandar el bounding box del mapa (map.getBounds().toJSON()) que te dará un objeto {south:xxx, west:xxx, north:xxx, east:xxx}, y con eso en la base de datos buscar los puntos usando lat > south AND lat < north AND lng > west AND lng < east.

Comment: Estoy empezando desde cero, he buscado ejemplos más sencillos y parto del siguiente: Lee los datos de la tabla MySQL y me muestra todos los marcadores y los datos en una tabla bajo el mapa:

Comment: El ejmplo está sacado de aquí: [https://blog.nubecolectiva.com/cargar-una-ubicacion-desde-la-base-de-datos-mysql-con-php-y-google-maps-javascript-api/]

Comment: Lo único que me faltaría ahora, es ver como añadir, por ejemplo, filtros para categorías, filtro tipo deslizante para filtrar por distancias, es decir, aplicar filtros a los resultados devueltos por el mapa al leer la base de datos. Perdón por mi ignorancia pero soy mega-novato

Comment: Y no hay posibilidad de que te cambies a MySQL 5.7?

Comment: De todos modos te recomiendo que, ya disipada la pregunta general, hagas otra pregunta aludiendo a la implementación que tienes ahora, incluyendo tu código, la tabla que dibujas, y la estructura con que guardas los datos en el frontend.